# Property 'pictures' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: typescript, recompose

I am trying to learn to use Recompose with Typescript. The code blow complies just fine, but it is giving me an error in the code editor. The problem is something to do with the passing `props` down to the HOC.

```
interface IPicture {
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}

interface IProps {
    pictures: IPicture[];
    index: number;
    prev: (len: number) => IEventListener;
    next: (len: number) => IEventListener;
}

interface IEventListener {
    handleEvent(evt: Event): void;
}

const PictureSlide: React.SFC<IProps> = ({ pictures, index, prev, next }) => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <img src={pictures[index].imageUrl} alt="picture" />
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    width: "100%",
                }}
            >
                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => prev(pictures.length)}>
                    Prev
                </Button>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => next(pictures.length)}>
                    Next
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Card>
    );
};

const enhancer = compose(
    withState("index", "updateIndex", 0),
    withHandlers({
        next: ({ updateIndex }) => (max: number) =>
            updateIndex((n: number) => (n === max ? 0 : n + 1)),
        prev: ({ updateIndex }) => (max: number) =>
            updateIndex((n: number) => (n === 0 ? max : n - 1)),
    })
);

export default enhancer(PictureSlide);
```

and import this component from another component:

```
<PictureSlide pictures={coverCropSlideImages} />
```

The file complies just fine, but I get a error in code editor saying:

> [ts] Property 'pictures' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<{ c...'.